# How does dynamic_cast fail?

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

According to what I read, performing a wrong run-time dynamic_cast can either throw a bad_cast exception or return zero.

Is it correct to say that it will return zero if you are casting pointers?

i.e:

```
class Base { virtual void a(){} };
class Derived: public Base {};

int main () {
  Base *base = new Base();
  dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base);
  return 0;
}
```

And that it will throw an bad_cast exception when casting objects?

i.e:

```
class Base { virtual void a(){} };
class Derived: public Base {};

int main () {
  Base base;
  Base& ref = base;
  dynamic_cast<Derived&>(ref);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` will return NULL on a bad cast if you are casting a pointer; it will throw `std::bad_cast` when casting *references*. It is a compile-time error to attempt to cast *objects* with `dynamic_cast` (eg, with `dynamic_cast<Derived>(base)`)

Comment: Ok, so the affirmation is correct. Thanks. I edited the message in order to make the base class polymorphic (adding the virtual function) and using reference casting for the exception to be thrown.